# xslt replace text with hyperlink

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to replace all occurrences of the word **Google** with the hyperlink `<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>`

Sounds easy enough, but I'm doing this within an xslt file. I could normally use the function replace, but it only works when replacing a string with a string (no elements are allowed).

Any help or pointers on this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is similar to this question: [Replacing strings in various XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596328/replacing-strings-in-various-xml-files)

You would just need to change what you're replacing.

Here's an example that shows a possible modification.

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <test>This should be a link to google: Google</test>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="list">
        <words>
            <word>
                <search>Google</search>
                <replace>http://www.google.com</replace>
            </word>
            <word>
                <search>Foo</search>
                <replace>http://www.foo.com</replace>
            </word>
        </words>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:variable name="search" select="concat('(',string-join($list/words/word/search,'|'),')')"/>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$search}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <a href="{$list/words/word[search=current()]/replace}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <test>This should be a link to google: <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
   </test>
</doc>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me at all, but I'll mark this as the answer - since it is thorough and it will lead me to the right path. It's sad how there's so much work required for doing a simple replace. Thanks again.

Comment: The word "Google" is still in the document (not a hyperlink), but it should work. It's on me now to make this work.

Comment: @HerbMeehan - Here's a working example. Hopefully it helps: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaGe

Comment: Thank you. I really mean it. Wish I could give you another upvote. Thanks.

Comment: @HerbMeehan - No problem at all. Glad I could help!