# Multiple replacements in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml that looks like below:

```
<tests>
<testcases id="1">
<command value="copy">
<files value="$$path$$/1.txt $$path$$/2.txt" />
</testcases>
```

My xsl file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:param name="path">##MISSING##</xsl:param>
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:param name="find">$$project$$</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="attribute-name" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(., $find)">
        <xsl:attribute name="{$attribute-name}">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., $find), $path, substring-after(., $find))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

When I run the xsl tool, I get the output as

```
<tests>
<testcases id="1">
<command value="copy">
<files value="E:/test/1.txt $$path$$/2.txt" />
</testcases>
```

Could you please suggest what needs to be done to replace the second $$path$$ ?

Comment: I'd suggest a recursive template call. Take a look at this excellent answer from JLRishe for a good XSLT 1.0 example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14597353/317052

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:variable name="path" select="'E:/test'"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:param name="find">$$path$$</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute-name" select="name()"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., $find)">
            <xsl:attribute name="{$attribute-name}">

                <xsl:call-template name="changeStrings">
                    <xsl:with-param name="val"  select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="find" select="$find"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$path"/>
                </xsl:call-template>                        


            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="changeStrings">
    <xsl:param name="val"/>
    <xsl:param name="path"/>
    <xsl:param name="find"/>

    <xsl:variable name="newval" select="concat(substring-before($val, $find), $path, substring-after($val, $find))"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($newval,'$$')">
            <xsl:call-template name="changeStrings">
                <xsl:with-param name="val" select="$newval"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="find" select="$find"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$path"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newval"/>                
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>


</xsl:template>
```

Note that I changed your parameter "path" to a variable, just to make it easier to run.
Also you were looking for $$project$$, not $$path$$.
There are better ways to do many of the things in this XLS.

Also here's the XML, which I changed a little

```
<tests>
<testcases id="1">
    <command value="copy">
        <files value="$$path$$/1.txt $$path$$/2.txt" />
    </command>
</testcases>
```

Comment: I must say that I'm disappointed. I supplied a working solution and Alok Ranjan didn't even bother to acknowledge it.